# Get Date Range from multiple Financial Year in SQL

Tags: sql

I am select FY from drop down (Multiple selection) and
I have multiple Financial Year Range,
2017-18,2018-19

I want date range in sql like this 01-Jan-2017 to 31-Dec-2019
i want to apply in between keyword for selection data.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: What keeps you from converting the user input into a proper DATE value so that you can use it in your SQL query?